# Pandora app won't play on Apple TV (4th Generation)

Tags: appletv

I can't get Pandora to play music on my Apple TV (4th Gen). It just sits there at 0:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason Pandora doesn't work with *Reduce Loud Sounds* enabled.

Disable it by going to the Settings app.

**Settings > Audio and Video > Reduce loud sounds > off**

EDIT: I just discovered you can **ask Siri to "Turn Reduce loud sounds off"** as well and it is much faster than navigating the settings of course.